# Flex AIR application certificate update not overriding the application

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an old Flex application deployed in client machine. Now the certificate of the original application is expired. I purchased a new license from Godaddy and created a new AIR installer for my customers.

Now the problem is the new installer while running in Windows is giving the error below. The message below is not exact from the application but this is what it means:

> The application cannot be installed due to a certificate problem.  The
>   certificate does not match the installed application certificate, does
>   not support application upgrades, or is invalid.  Please contact the
>   application author.

Now my question is, do I need to use the expired certificate and resign it and reuse it. Can't I use a new certificate. My ultimate goal is my customers should me able to install the application and that should override/update the old application.

Comment: You'll need to uninstall the previous version and reinstall the new application.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me. :)

Comment: You may still be able to use the previous certificate in some cases. Here's my experience on it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143622/getting-the-error-the-application-cannot-be-installed-due-to-a-certificate.

Comment: Uninstalling the previous version resolved the issue for me as well.