# Getting the error, "The application cannot be installed due to a certificate..."

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I'm getting the following error when trying to upgrade an application I wrote:

> **Sorry an error occurred**
>
> The application cannot be installed due to a certificate problem.  The
>   certificate does not match the installed application certificate, does
>   not support application upgrades, or is invalid.  Please contact the
>   application author.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm the application author. I recently created a new project and copied the old project files to the new location.

Is this due to that or am I possibly using a different certificate somehow? In the drop down list I have multiple entries pointing to same cert. I will try going through them but I'm wondering too if it's possible if anyone else has run into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the incorrect cert. When I created a new project, Flash Builder preloaded certs from somewhere. They looked correct, however, the cert I was using was not in that list. So I opened the previous project and found a cert from that the project was using. After recompiling and attempting to update, the install went correctly with no error.